# How to make my session variable available to the models with Thread variable?

Tags: ruby, session, model-view-controller

I have a sessions variable that stores the **group id**. I have set a before filter in my application controller that sets the session[:group_id]

```
 # In my application controller  
 before_filter :save_request_path

 def save_request_path
  if request.params[:group_id]
    session[:group_id]= request.params[:group_id]
  end
end
```

At this point I am trying to access this session variable inside a model. I have seen an example of doing it for current_user using Thread variable. I do not seem to understand such example however https://www.zorched.net/2007/05/29/making-session-data-available-to-models-in-ruby-on-rails/.
How would I do this using the thread variable in my specific case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a thread variable, I'd recommend using [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store), which avoids concurrency issues by using thread-local variables.

This is how you'd store the value:

```
def save_request_path
  if request.params[:group_id]
    RequestStore.store[:group_id] = request.params[:group_id]
  end
end
```

And this is how you access it:

```
RequestStore.store[:group_id]
```